# Firefox loading all css files referenced in conditional comments

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox, cross-browser

I have a regular `CSS` file plus two IE specific `CSS` files. In Firebug in Firefox I noticed the same `<div>` is getting properties from the three files.

Why is Firefox loading `iestyle.css` & `ie6style.css`?

```
<!--[if IE 7]>  
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="iestyle.css" />
<![endif]-->

<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="ie6style.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

**Addition**

[image]

Comment: Are you sure? What styles is the div getting? I think you may be mistaken. It would help seeing a live demo or something.

Comment: Yes.. see the image. Site is not public.

Comment: maybe show us all the head of your html?

Answer (score 0):

This should definitely be working. Are you sure there isn't an unclosed `<!--` or `<![CDATA[` hanging around in `head`?

Answer (score 0):

I think that isn't all the relevant code. Do you perhaps `@include` those files somewhere else?

Answer (score -2):

Are the conditional comments in the HEAD element or in the BODY element? I haven't tried it, but it's possible that FF only ignores conditional comments if they are in the HEAD element (where they should be).

Comment: Firefox doesn't ignore conditionals